# Can I make the trace module count a genexp as run once per invocation?

Tags: python, code-coverage

How to change the output of `python -m trace --count sample.py` to this?

input: `sample.py`

```
a = (i for i in (1,2,3))
list(a)
```

Current output: `sample.cover`

```
    5: a = (i for i in (1,2,3))
    1: list(a)
```

I want to change this output like below, so it tells only the number of times the line was run, without counting the loop's evaluation as extra iterations:

```
    1: a = (i for i in (1,2,3))
    1: list(a)
```

Is it possible?
Do I need to modify `trace` module?
If so where to modify in `trace` module?

Comment: Is this your full code?

Comment: @user1767754: Yes it is.

Comment: Going forward, please try to write a question title that actually describes your individual question without needing to read the text to know what "like this" is. (I've edited appropriately here).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Sorry and thanks. The title is now what I should write.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you need that? I mean every line would run one time right?

Comment: @user1767754: Because I want to see how many times each line passed without inserting the code like `print(cnt)` every line. I think it's conviniet for debugging. I thought using `trace` module directly will solve my problem but unfortunately it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING:**
I don't know the mechanism about `trace` module at all.
And not tested at all
So please don't trust this code.

I modified the `trace` module.
I don't know why, but it seems working except first meaningless line needed...

https://github.com/keimina/python_trace/blob/master/trace.py

input: `sample.py`

```
xxx = "This first line of code is needed for working my trace.py because of my poor knowledge"

def c():
    return [i for i in (1,2,3)]

def d():
    for i in (1,2,3):
        pass

a = (i for i in (1,2,3))
b = iter([i for i in (1,2,3)])

list(a)
list(b)

for i in (1,2,3,4,5):
    c()

d()
```

output: `sample.cover`

```
       xxx = "This first line of code is needed for working my trace.py because of my poor knowledge"

    1: def c():
    5:     return [i for i in (1,2,3)]

    1: def d():
    4:     for i in (1,2,3):
    3:         pass

    1: a = (i for i in (1,2,3))
    1: b = iter([i for i in (1,2,3)])

    1: list(a)
    1: list(b)

    6: for i in (1,2,3,4,5):
    5:     c()

    1: d()
```

Comment: I'd suggest filtering on `key` rather than `lineno` -- as I read it, the change at https://github.com/keimina/python_trace/commit/5ea2cfff31ec1ace4a2e6ca3f3c76f83218e52d7 would ignore a call from a function in one module to a function in another, if the callee is at the same line as the caller. Otherwise, though, that looks like a good fix.